# reading the value of header in response X-XSS-protection response header

Tags: java, httpresponse

I am implementing a filter to set

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
```

I have written the filter. I want to check if its working perfect or not.

I thought to read the header from response object. But I don't know how to do that.

Can any one tell how to do it.

Or if there is abetter way of doing it, let me know.

**Edit**

Updating the code

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException 
            {   

        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        //set  X-XSS-protection in http header, other http headers can be added in same way
        String value = enable ? "1" : "0";  

        if(block) 
        {
            value += "; mode=block";
        }    

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("ready to set xss");
        response.setHeader("X-XSS-protection", value);
        out.println("<br/><br/>Xss has been set");          
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
        out.println("<br/><br/>XSS"+request.getHeader("X-XSS-protection"));     

        out.println("<br/><br/>job done");
    }
```

I am getting **"XSSnull"**

Please help me how do I correct it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you're able to put your filter around a simple servlet, you could prop it up in a Jetty/Tomcat container and execute `curl -i http://localhost:8080/context-root/foo` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get and read the response reader like this

```
request.getHeader("name of the header");
```

I am guessing in your case you are aiming for something like this

```
request.getHeader("X-XSS-Protection");
```

**EDIT**

for more clarification, you can think of a little analogy of Request and Response.

- Request - What you are sending.
- Response - What you are receiving

for more information about Request and Response please refer to [this](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) guide, if will containt all the information you need about Request and Response headers. Go specifically to `'Handling Http Response Headers'`

Comment: Thank you for the response. can you clarify on how request.getHeader get response header.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment would consider rephrasing it. I have updated it.

Comment: My apologies for creating confusion. "request.getHeader" is actually reading request object right. Will it read response header.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. I tried that but I am getting null value. Can you help to correct it.

Comment: how did you do it? did you redirect the page? or did you past the response and request, if you did a redirect it would automatically flush all the current Request and response headers.

Comment: did you do a response redirect?